# Eclipse Pydev: Stops at breakpoint, but code line isn't highlighted and actions are not selectable

Tags: eclipse, pydev

I'm running my Django project in Pydev Debug mode. It stops at breakpoints and shows the debug actions (step into, etc). However, the code line is not highlighted and the debug actions are not selectable. I only have the one breakpoint.

The 'Debug' view is selected (next to Pydev and Java view options).

If I remove the breakpoint then the program runs through so it really is the breakpoint causing the program to pause. Also, the Eclipse icon in the Windows task manager starts blinking like it does when it reaches a breakpoint.

I'm going nuts!

I've tried removing and reinstalling Pydev, but no luck. And tried resetting the perspetive. No luck,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to go to Run/Debug preference page (which I found via help. Not sure of the menu path,)

Then check: "Activate the debug view when a breakpoint is hit."

Uncheck the Activate workbench option.